# Backspace in terminal output

Tags: terminal-output

Is there a way to insert a backspace character while writing to the terminal? I'd like to remove the space character that is automatically inserted between two calls of `\message{}`:

```
\message{.}\message{.}\message{.}
\bye
```

is written as `. . .` to the terminal but I want `...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `texio` library provided by `luatex` provides more control over message formatting and does not insert a space:

```
\def\mymessage#1{\directlua{texio.write("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}
\mymessage{.}\mymessage{.}\mymessage{.}
\bye
```

The result is:

```
grendel:io sharpie$ luatex io.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.60.2-2010071218 (TeX Live 2010) (rev 3736) 
(./io.tex... )
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sharpie. Using Lua would indeed be a solution here.

Answer (score 6):

This space is, as far as I know, impossible to avoid between two separate `\message`s. The solution would be to first combine all the contiguous material in one macro (adding material with `\edef\foo{\foo <material>}`), and then doing `\message{\foo}`.

To really know where the space comes from, look in `tex.web`, documented source code of TeX. The relevant procedure seems to be `procedure issue_message;`, which calls `@<Print string |s| on the terminal@>`, defined as follows.

```
@ @<Print string |s| on the terminal@>=
begin if term_offset+length(s)>max_print_line-2 then print_ln
else if (term_offset>0)or(file_offset>0) then print_char(" ");
slow_print(s); update_terminal;
end
```

I *think* that `print_char(" ")` is the culprit. A related [question on `\write`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8085/2707) rather than `\message` was answered by @TH. last January, and he introduced me to reading `tex.web`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. Collecting the material before printing it eventually is not a solution in my case because I want to output dots as a progress indicator while reading chunks of larger binary files.

Comment: @Alexander Grahn: that's a good reason then. I was wondering why anyone would really need that, since the precise log mostly doesn't matter.